# C99 complex support with visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, c99, complex-numbers

I would like to use complex numbers as defined in C99, but I need to support compilers which do not support it (MS compilers come to mind).

I don't need many functions, and implementing the needed functions on compilers without support is not too difficult. But I have a hard time implementing the 'type' itself. Ideally, I would like to do something like:

```
#ifndef HAVE_CREAL
double creal(complex z)
{
/* .... */
}
#endif

#ifndef HAVE_CREALF
float creal(float complex z)
{
/* ... */
}
#endif
```

But I am not sure I see how to do this if the compiler cannot recognize 'float complex'. I would actually think it is impossible, but the C library by [Dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com/c99.aspx) seems to indicate otherwise. What is the solution ? I don't mind using functions/macros for operations on the type, but I need a way to assign values to a complex number, and get back its real/imaginary part in a way whichi is compatible with C99.

## Solution

I ended up doing something like this:

```
#ifdef USE_C99_COMPLEX
#include <complex.h>
typedef complex my_complex;
#else
typedef struct {
  double x, y;
} my_complex;
#endif

/*
 * Those unions are used to convert a pointer of my_complex to native C99
 * complex or our own complex type indenpendently on whether C99 complex
 * support is available
 */
#ifdef USE_C99_COMPLEX
typedef union {
    my_complex my_z;
    complex c99_z;
} __complex_to_c99_cast;
#else
typedef union {
    my_complex my_z;
    my_complex c99_z;
} __complex_to_c99_cast;
#endif
```

for the type definition, and as follows to define a set of complex functions:

```
#ifndef HAVE_CREAL
double my_creal(my_complex z)
{
    union {
            my_complex z;
            double a[2];
    } z1;
    z1.z = z;
    return z1.a[0];
}
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_CREAL
my_complex my_creal(ny_complex z)
{
    __complex_to_c99_cast z1;
    __complex_to_c99_cast ret;

    z1.my_z = z;
    ret.c99_z = creal(z1.c99_z);
    return ret.npy_z;
}
#endif
```

That's a bit complicated, but this enables me to easily reuse C lib functions when available, and it can be partly automated through code generator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter what you do, you can't make "float complex" parse properly in a non-C99 compiler. So instead of writing that, make some typedefs. It's far easier if you only have to support one complex type, so I'll just demonstrate with `float complex`.

First, define the types:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
//using a C99 compiler
#include &lt;complex.h>
typedef float _Complex float_complex;
#else
typedef struct 
{
    float re, im;
} float_complex;
#endif
```

Then, we need to be able to create complex numbers, and emulate creal and cimag.

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
//creal, cimag already defined in complex.h

inline complex_float make_complex_float(float real, float imag)
{
   return real + imag * I;
}
#else
#define creal(z) ((z).re)
#define cimag(z) ((z).im)

extern const complex_float complex_i; //put in a translation unit somewhere
#define I complex_i
inline complex_float make_complex_float(float real, float imag)
{
    complex_float z = {real, imag};
    return z;
}
#endif
```

Next, write functions that wrap addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and comparisons.

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define add_complex(a, b) ((a)+(b))
//similarly for other operations
#else //not C99
inline float_complex add_complex(float_complex a, float_complex b)
{
  float_complex z = {a.re + b.re, a.im + b.im};
  return z;
}
//similarly for subtract, multiply, divide, and comparison operations.
```

Note that `add_complex(c, 5)` doesn't work in C89 mode in the above code, because the compiler doesn't know how to make 5 into a complex. This is a tricky problem to fix in C without compiler support -- you have to resort to tricks like the new `tgmath.h` uses, which are compiler-specific.

Unfortunately, the effect of all of this is that the nice C99 syntax like `a+b` to add complex numbers has to be written `add_complex(a, b)`.

Another option (as another poster pointed to) is to use C++ `std::complex` on non-C99 compilers. This might be OK if you can wrap things in typedefs and `#ifdef`s. However, you'd require either C++ or C99.

Comment: C++ does not work, because you cannot have std::complex in the signature of functions with C linkage. I could add a wrapper around this, but then, there is not much point in using C++ at all. As the project does not depend on C++ for now, that represents a big dependency anyway - I need to support many platforms, not just recent gcc and MS compilers.

Comment: If you are worried about what style of linkage you're using, I presume you need to have link-time (binary) compatibility between object files compiled at different times, not just source compatibility. In that case, it might be better to always use the struct float_complex approach. Otherwise, someone could compile a file in a compiler's C89 mode, try to call a function in a library compiled in C99 mode, and see strange results because the calling conventions for _Complex and float_complex structs aren't the same.

Comment: I agree with Doug: If you want C99/C89 compatible code, you won't use the + operators on your float_complex structs, so there is little interest in having two types, one C99 complex, and you in-house complex struct.

Answer (score -1):

There is a  library that I found on the msdn website. Here's a link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0352zzhd.aspx

I hope that helps.

Comment: It is the C++ `<complex>` header. As long as the question author is stuck with C, there's no way he/she will be able to use it properly.