# CVXOPT installation fails at complex type declaration in file misc.h

Tags: python, c, cvxopt

When attempting to install the cxvopt package for Python, using pip on Windows, I get the following error messages:

```
misc.h(35): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'z'
misc.h(35): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'z'
misc.h(36): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
```

... and so on.

The error occurs in the file misc.h (referenced in base.c) at the complex variable declaration shown below:

```
#ifndef NO_ANSI99_COMPLEX
typedef union {
  double d;
  int_t i;
  double complex z;
} number;
#endif
```

This does not happen on another computer I am using. Both have Visual Studio 14.0 installed, as required.

Can anyone who has seen this problem suggest a solution?  (My first thought was to include "complex.h", but that was referenced in cvxopt.h, which was included in base.c before misc.h.)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 14.0 has a pathetic ANSI C89 compiler, which doesn't even support [the *obsolete* ISO C99 standard that this code requires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063406/c99-complex-support-with-visual-studio). I guess you are to define the macro `NO_ANSI99_COMPLEX` for the compilation to succeed; if this macro is defined, the code skips the C99 specific constructs.

I believe this macro was defined when you successfully compiled the code on the other computer?

Answer (score 0):

cvxopt is not supported on windows for python versions after 3.4 and I couldn't get it to build for the reasons outlined in the other answer. I'm using conda and I have created a seperate environment for python 3.4 and installed cvxopt using pip and it worked fine as there are prebuilt binaries for that version of Python. I've also got the visual studio cpp build tools installed for VS14

(In conda command prompt running as administrator)

```
//Setup vcvars using batch file change to whatever path and version of vcvars is correct for you 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
//setup new environment using python 3.4 
conda create -n py34 python=3.4.5 anaconda
//switch to new environment 
activate py34
//install cvxopt
pip install cvxopt
```