# Why tanh function from math.h library give wrong result?

Tags: c, math.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define PI 2*acos(0.0)
int main(void)
{
    double theta;
    theta=tanh(1/(sqrt(3.0)));
    printf("With tanh function = %lf\n",theta);
    printf("Actual value = %lf\n",PI/6.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

With tanh function = 0.520737

Actual value = 0.523599

Why are these two values different? It should me same as my understanding.

Comment: [The need for parentheses in macros in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10820340/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc note in this case it should evaluate to the same result

Comment: @immibis yes I know. It's just a behavior one should get familiar with

Comment: Neither the inaccuracy of floating-point numbers nor the missing parentheses on the macro is the problem. I calculated tanh(1/sqrt(3.0)) on an HP42S emulator and got 0.520736883716. Are you **sure** that the expected result is pi/6?

Comment: But you should definitely parenthesize your macro definition anyway: `#define PI (2*acos(0.0))`. It happens not to matter for this program because of the way you use it, but missing parentheses could cause problems in other contexts. An example: https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/42

Comment: According to wolfram (http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tanh/03/02/) tanh(πi/6) is i/sqrt(3). Here `i` is the imaginary unit (that is, the square root of -1). You can't just divide out the `i`s, and anyway you seem to be reversing tanh and atanh. I think you can deduce the identity from the identity e^iπ=-1

Comment: In what way is this result "ambiguous", as you say in the title? It's either right or it's wrong, but there's no confusion about the value.

Comment: @AndrewLi: No, it's not a floating-point accuracy problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ahh yes. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 6):

You've got that identity completely wrong.

The actual identity is

tanh<sup>-1</sup>(*i* ⁄ √3) = π*i* ⁄ 6 (where *i* is the imaginary unit, √-1)

C11 can easily validate that:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<complex.h>

int main(void)
{
    complex double theta=catanh(I/sqrt(3.0));
    printf("With atanh function = %lf\n",cimag(theta));
    printf("Actual value = %lf\n",M_PI/6);
    return 0;
}
```

(Live on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3df5358a2be67cd):

```
With atanh function = 0.523599
Actual value = 0.523599
```

`M_PI` will be in `math.h` in any Posix compliant system. Apparently, on Windows you use

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
```

but I have no idea whether Visual Studio supports `complex.h`.

Comment: MS only writes C++ compiler and never have the intention of supporting C99 fully in Visual Studio so you have to use the [C++ <complex>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0352zzhd.aspx) header or write a [wrapper in C for your own](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1063406/995714)

Answer (score 3):

Your program has a couple of minor flaws, but none that cause it to misbehave.

Your `PI` macro should be parenthesized:

```
#define PI (2*acos(0.0))
```

but you happen to get away without the parentheses because of the way you use it.

The correct format for printing a `double` value is actually `%f`, but `%lf` is accepted as well.  (`%Lf` is for `long double`.  `%f` also works for `float`, because `float` arguments to variadic functions are promoted to `double`).  This also doesn't affect your program's behavior.

In fact, your program is working correctly.  I've confirmed using an HP 42S emulator that `tanh(1/(sqrt(3.0)))` is approximately 0.520737 (I get 0.520736883716).

The problem is your assumption that the result should be π/6.0.  It isn't.

Comment: I have also tested in matlab 2014b. Had to discard my almost written answer. :D