# How do I use C99 complex numbers with clang on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, clang, c99

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 and it comes wih clang.  I can successfully compile and link applications with `clang`.

When I `#include <complex.h>` however, I do not get standard compliant complex numbers.

Here is an example that does not work after including `<complex.h>`.

```
complex float z = 2.0f + 3.0f * I;
```

It tells me the `complex` keyword is undeclared.

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'complex'
```

However, I am able to use Microsoft non-standard complex numbers.  Here is a complete program that works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  _Fcomplex z = { 2.0f, 3.0f };

  printf( "z = %f + %f * i\n", crealf( z ), cimagf( z ) ); 
  return 0;
}
```

And I can compile and link it with `clang -m64 -o cmplx.exe cmplx.c`.  The output is predictably

```
z = 2.000000 + 3.000000 * i
```

Can I get standard compliant complex numbers with clang on Windows?

Comment: Does `_Complex` work? AFAIK even if you use clang, the library still comes from VS. And VS isn't really C99 compliant.

Comment: Yes, _Complex "works" but I can't create an imaginary number because `I` is of the type `_Fcomplex` from what I gather from the error message.

Comment: Yeah, just as I thought. You're out of luck. You can't get the actual library support for `complex.h`. mingw might be a better option for C on Windows... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler and the libraries it's using are separate. Even though you're compiling with `clang`, [you're still using Microsoft's non-standard libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/complex-math-support?view=vs-2019#types-used-in-complex-math).

> The Microsoft implementation of the complex.h header defines these types as equivalents for the C99 standard native complex types:
>
> ```
> Standard type                                   Microsoft type
> float complex or float _Complex                 _Fcomplex
> double complex or double _Complex               _Dcomplex
> long double complex or long double _Complex     _Lcomplex
> ```

You can smooth some of this over with typdefs and macros, [as demonstrated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1063835/14660).